# How to create a Zul template of a button and then apply it

Tags: zk

The example provided in the zkessentials book is too simplistic yet the documentation goes way overboard (in my opinion).

What I'd like to do is create a template with just a button and pass it it's style class and it's label value.

The example in the book shows a ten-line Zul and then says you have to declare its a template but does not mention where nor does it mention how to pass values to the template.

The other examples introduce `@{define(left)}` and `@{insert(left)}` which obviously with no explanation makes it pretty difficult to make it out if I can just pass values there or if it's doing some matching.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to make a predefined class who extends button.

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements BeforeCompose {

    @Override
    public void beforeCompose() {
        setLabel("new Button");
        setStyle("...");
        // and more settings you want to set as default
    }
}
```

Now you have this class you can use it in 3 different ways.
First of all :

```
<button use="my.path.MyButton"/>
```

Second :

```
<?component name="mybutton" class="my.path.MyButton"?>
<mybutton />
```

Thirth :

Add this in lang-addon.xml :

```
<component>
    <component-name>mybutton</component-name>
    <extends>button</extends>
    <component-class>my.path.MyButton</component-class>
</component>
```

and usage in zul :

```
<mybutton />
```